# Help with a function that will place a map pin for all posts

Tags: posts, customization, map

I have a custom post type called "properties".  When I add a property on the admin side, I input an address and then click a button that says "Place Pin At Address".  I have uploaded thousands of properties with addresses but I need to run the "Place pin at address" function on all of them.  It is time consuming to go through every post and push the button and then publish.

I thought I could do something like:

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'SetMapPointer' );
```

Unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question but I am pretty sure the code of `SetMapPointer()` is going to be important. Can you post that?

Comment: The theme i have installed has a javascript folder that has a bunch of google maps functions.  I was just guessing that SetMapPointer might be the right function to call.

Comment: I'll see if I can explain it better - Basically I have several thousand custom posts on my site.  I need to place a pin on a map for each post.  Currently I have to go through every single post and push the "Place pin at address" button which creates a pin and places in on a google map on the homepage of the site.  I was hoping there would be a faster way than manually doing this.  Is that any more clear?

Comment: It's clear but how would anyone here know without access to the theme?  Which I'm guessing isn't free either.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this and this is my first time posting here.  I have no problem giving access to the theme if it will help.  Free?  I didn't create the theme, I'm just trying to modify it a little.

Am I on the right track at all with the add_action hook?